# Find server details when connection lost with client

Tags: wcf

I have a code to access multiple wcf server from one client with multiple instances. if any connection lost between this, having faulted/closed event trigger function to hande this.

`((ICommunicationObject)notificationProviderClient).Faulted += new EventHandler(myHost_Faulted);
((ICommunicationObject)notificationProviderClient).Closed += new EventHandler(myHost_Closed);`

`void myHost_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e)`
`{`

`}`

`void myHost_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {`

`}`

The above function get called, if any connection get fault/closed.
 In this scenarion how to find which wcf server connection lost with the clent? is there any possible to find this or we have to go for another method to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to find remote address of server during connection lost, use this on client side

`this.notificationProviderClient.InnerDuplexChannel.Faulted += new EventHandler(myHost_Faulted);`

`void myHost_Faulted(object sender, EventArgs e) {`

```
    IContextChannel channel = sender as IContextChannel;

    if (channel  != null)
    {
      var remoteAddrs = a1.RemoteAddress;
    }
```

`}`